# How can I update the Market app on my device?

Tags: google-play-store, htc-desire-s

I have an HTC Desire S with Android 2.3. After I purchased my phone Google released an update for the Android Market, but I haven't receive this update. How can I update to the new version of the Market?

Answer (score 3):

New versions of the Market are rolled-out by Google automatically (and there is a slight chance that you never see the new Market, but I don't think that this is true for the Desire S). So the best thing is to wait.

If you really can't wait you could try [this market.apk](http://www.multiupload.com/41FQ6PQ3MS), but I am not sure if it's the latest. Make sure that you have "Unknown sources" enabled. <sup>[Source](http://phandroid.com/2011/08/24/download-the-latest-android-market-update-and-install-it-manually/)</sup>